# How to set background image for button?

Tags: apache-flex

```
<mx:Button id="callButton" x="35" y="6" width="202" height="45" label="Call" alpha="1.0"
borderColor="#FFF600" click="callOneClick(event)"
fillAlphas="[0.94, 1.0, 0.47, 0.47]" fillColors="[#FEDC00, #FEBC00]" fontSize="16"/>
```

This is the button I'm using in my mxml file. How can I set `.png` background image to my button and still have button label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex 3 mx buttons allow you to set an image as the background for a button by setting the skin attributes in MXML. You can set different states using the up/over/down values. Your label will appear above the images you set but fillColours and fillAlphas will no longer have any effect.

```
<mx:Button id="callButton" 
    label="Call"
    overSkin="@Embed(source='../assets/over_skin.png')"
    upSkin="@Embed(source='../assets/up_skin.png')"
    downSkin="@Embed(source='../assets/down_skin.png')"/>
```

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=skinning_3.html

You could also assign them using styles in your CSS and setting the `styleName` property of the button. Your CSS would look like this:

```
.myButtonStyle {
    upSkin: ClassReference("../assets/up_skin.png");
    overSkin: ClassReference("../assets/over_skin.png");
    downSkin: ClassReference("../assets/down_skin.png");
}
```